# How to fix perspective of an image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an input image which contains a letter inside a box, what I want to do is to fix the perspective of the image so I can easily use it with my letter recognition model.
This is the code that I use for pre-processing:

```py
def preprocess(image):
    # Convert to grayscale
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # NOISE REMOVAL - START
    # Apply CLAHE (makes the image lightness more uniform)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
    image = clahe.apply(image)

    cv2.imwrite("preprocess_stages/0_clahe.png", image)

    # Apply NlMeansDenoising (removes noise but loses some details)
    image = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(image, None, 10, 7, 21)

    cv2.imwrite("preprocess_stages/1_nl_means_denoising.png", image)

    # Apply GaussianBlur with a medium kernel (removes noise but loses some edges)
    image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)

    cv2.imwrite("preprocess_stages/2_gaussian_blur.png", image)
    # NOISE REMOVAL - END

    # Apply OTSU thresholding (we need the letter to be white)
    _, image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    cv2.imwrite("preprocess_stages/3_otsu.png", image)

    # Morphological erosion (removes noise and small objects)
    kernel = np.ones((10, 10), np.uint8)
    image = cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations=1)

    cv2.imwrite("preprocess_stages/4_morphological_erosion.png", image)

    return image
```

I have seen many example on the internet and most of them require the 4 corner points to be provided as input too... there are few examples on how to calculate them and most of them don't work for my case, nonetheless I've tried writing something:

UPDATE: I successfully wrote a working code, even though I changed the Morphological Opening to a simple Erosion since it works better for me.

```py
def fix_perspective_convex_hull(preprocessed):
    # RETR_TREE retrieves all of the contours and reconstructs a full hierarchy of nested contours
    # used for maximum accuracy (my deduction)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(preprocessed, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Draw all contours to a new image
    image = cv2.cvtColor(preprocessed, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imwrite("perspective_stages/0_contours.png", image)

    for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
        hull = cv2.convexHull(contour)

        # Reduce to quadrilateral
        epsilon = 0.1 * cv2.arcLength(hull, True) 
        approximated = cv2.approxPolyDP(hull, epsilon, True)

        # Draw approximated contour
        image = cv2.cvtColor(preprocessed, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approximated], -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)

        cv2.imwrite("perspective_stages/1_approximated_contour_{}.png".format(i), image)

        if len(approximated) == 4:
            image = cv2.cvtColor(preprocessed, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
            cv2.drawContours(image, [approximated], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

            cv2.imwrite("perspective_stages/2_final_contour.png", image)

            letter_hull = [a[0] for a in approximated] # Remove extra dimension [[x, y]] -> [x, y]
            break

    # Create placeholder for rectangle points
    rectangle = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype="float32")

    # Top-left point has smallest sum
    # Bottom-right point has largest sum
    # sum = x + y
    s = np.sum(letter_hull, axis=1)
    rectangle[0] = letter_hull[np.argmin(s)]
    rectangle[2] = letter_hull[np.argmax(s)]

    # Top-right point has smallest difference
    # Bottom-left point has largest difference
    # difference = x - y
    d = np.diff(letter_hull, axis=1)
    rectangle[1] = letter_hull[np.argmin(d)]
    rectangle[3] = letter_hull[np.argmax(d)]

    # Compute width and height of new image based on points
    (top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left) = rectangle

    # Width may be either top-right to top-left or bottom-right to bottom-left
    # TL;DR: Pythagorean theorem 
    width_top = np.sqrt(((top_right[0] - top_left[0]) ** 2) + ((top_right[1] - top_left[1]) ** 2))
    width_bottom = np.sqrt(((bottom_right[0] - bottom_left[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_right[1] - bottom_left[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_top), int(width_bottom))

    # Height may be either top-right to bottom-right or top-left to bottom-left
    # TL;DR: Pythagorean theorem 
    height_right = np.sqrt(((top_right[0] - bottom_right[0]) ** 2) + ((top_right[1] - bottom_right[1]) ** 2))
    height_left = np.sqrt(((top_left[0] - bottom_left[0]) ** 2) + ((top_left[1] - bottom_left[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_right), int(height_left))

    # Create destination points
    destination = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [width - 1, 0],
        [width - 1, height - 1],
        [0, height - 1]
    ], dtype="float32")

    # Compute perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rectangle, destination)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(preprocessed, matrix, (width, height))

    # Add padding
    warped = cv2.copyMakeBorder(warped, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0, 0, 0))

    # Return warped image
    return warped
```

Results:
[image]

Original

[image]

Preprocessed

[image]

Finding a quadrilateral

[image]

Warped

[image]

Inverted and resized for the neural network

UPDATE 2: My code only works for letters without curves, such as the H. When I try to run the code on curve letters (such as the S) I get the following results:
[image]

Comment: Without a camera model or a corresponding face-on image, you have to estimate. Find the 4 corners of your letter in the input. Decide how large you want the output letter to be i.e. its width and height. Compute the corners for those dimensions for the output. Get the homography for the two sets of 4 point x,y values. Do warpPerspective.

Comment: @fmw42 That's the issue that I'm facing, I can't find a working way to find the 4 corners of my input letter.

Comment: All you need is the corners of your white quadrilateral. (Get the contour of the white quadrilateral and then reduce points to 4 using approxPolyDp().  Or you can do corner detection on the black "H" and/or use the convex hull to get a quadrilateral. You may want to reduce the points to a quadrilateral using appropPolyDP()

Comment: As a test example, it would be better if your white quadrilateral were not clipped at the bottom left, so that you have a good sharp corner

Comment: @fmw42 I may not always have a white quadrilateral, it's very dependant on the place where the photo is taken from. What I'm interested in is to just cut the letter.

Comment: What do you mean cut the letter?  Can't you just threshold to separate it?  If not, please show a real photo and explain your issue?

Comment: @fmw42 I'm sorry, I didn't explain myself well. When thresholding a small letter on a big surface it may happen that all the background is all white with a small H in the center of the screen. What could happen is that it would treat all the photo as "the container", thus not resizing the photo at all.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand -- "container"? Why can you not extract a small letter as well as a big one?  I guess I need to see a real example and what code you are using to extract it.

Comment: @fmw42 I'm currently editing the question so I can show you some examples

Comment: @fmw42 Added the examples and the code that I use, also specified what I exactly want to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250636/discussion-between-fmw42-and-r1d3r175).